# UI Router - Condition in url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here in following code I have to change url on condition of add, subtract and multiply.
I want to add condition for add, subtract and multiply in url, something like `/:add?:subtract?:multiply`
so if I click on `add()` function only `/:add have to work in url same if I click on`sub()`function only`/:subtract` have to work in url

**State**

```
angular.module("app");
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('main', {
// here in url I have to apply conditions
      'url': '/:add/:subtract/:multiply',
      'abstract': true,
      'templateUrl': '/main.html',
      'controller': 'MainController'
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('LandingController', function ($rootScope, $scope, $state) {
    $scope.add = false;
    $scope.subtract = false;
    $scope.multiply = false;
    $scope.add = function () {
        $state.go("main.addition", {'add': true}, {'reload': true});
    };
    $scope.sub = function () {
        $state.go("main.subtraction", {'subtract': true}, {'reload': true});
    };
    $scope.multiply = function () {
        $state.go("main.multiplication", {'multiply': true}, {'reload': true});
    };
})

============= Main controller =================

.controller('MainController', function ($scope, $stateParams) {
    $scope.add = $stateParams.add;
    $scope.subtract = $stateParams.subtract;
    $scope.multiply = $stateParams.multiply;
});
```

When I click on `add()` method it has to redirect to url `'/true/addition..'`
When I click on `sub()` method it has to redirect to url `'/true/subtraction..'`
When I click on `multiply()` method it has to redirect to url `'/true/multiplication..'`

But my problem is right now it is redirecting to url `'/true///addition'` **or** `'//true//subtraction'` **or** `'///true/multiplication'` it is showing the right page
but when I refresh the page that time url get changed and crash the application.

**main.html**

```
<div ng-if="add" > Addition </div>
<div ng-if="subtract" > Subtraction </div>
<div ng-if="multiply" > Multiplication </div>
```

**landing.html**

```
<a href="#" ng-click="add()"> Addition </a>
<a href="#" ng-click="sub()"> Subtraction </a>
<a href="#" ng-click="multiply()"> Multiplication </a>
```

Here add, subtract, multiply are Boolean variables which are getting from `$state.go`.

Comment: I wouldn't use booleans myself. I would use normal text, enum style: `"add", "sub", "multiply"` and just use strategy logic to choose which parameter to set on the scope. That would look better in the URL

Comment: yes @CallumLinington you are right, but even if we use enum style variables then also how to apply condition on it.?

Comment: From high a level what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Here actually when I click on `add( )` function it goes with the url `'/true///addition'`. instead of this it has to go on url `'/true/addition'` same for subtraction it is going on url `'//true//subtraction'` instead of this it has to go on `'/true/subtraction'`
because of wrong url when I reload the page it is going on fuggy url, which is having no content like `'/true///'`

Answer (score 2):

I think your trying to achieve this:

```
 $stateProvider
    .state('main', {
      'url': '/',
      'abstract': true,
      'templateUrl': '/main.html',
      'controller': 'MainController'
    })
    .state('main.addition',{
      url: ':a/addition'
    })
    .state('main.subtraction',{
      url: ':b/subtraction'
    })
    .state('main.multiplication',{
      url: ':c/multiplication'
    });
```

**main.html**

```
<div ui-view=""></div>
```

**landing.html**

```
<a ui-sref="main.addition({a:true})"> Addition </a>
<a ui-sref="main.subtraction({b:true})"> Subtraction </a>
<a ui-sref="main.multiplication({c:true})"> Multiplication </a>
```

Hard to say what for do you need these parameters: a,b,c.

Here's a working `jsfiddle` - http://jsfiddle.net/irhabi/gsrg9cok/

I think it should look like this http://jsfiddle.net/irhabi/enurj8uu/

Comment: yes you are right but I have to apply condition on content which is available in `main.html` and that's why I am using those varibles in `stateParams`.
I updated a, b, c variables in my question

Comment: @ojuskulkarni
Check my jsfiddle in answer above. 
You don't need these params (a,b,c) because state name defines it.

Comment: yes your fiddle is right but I have some fields in `main.html` and main is parent state so when ever it goes on different pages `main.html` content is always same for its child pages and I want to hide and show some content on `main.html` page

Comment: @ojuskulkarni Did you define other states? main.addition, main.substraction ... ?

Comment: yes I already have other states and all those states are working fine

Comment: I tried in this way, But I have one issue if I have three different `<div>` or any other content in `main.html` and I have to show each `<div>` on condition i.e if state is `main.addition({a:true})` then I have to show `div 1` similarly if state is `main.subtraction({b:true})` then I have to show `div 2` and hide other. then in such condition how to apply condition in `main.html`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to give the url's separately. because, looking at the  number of times it is taking '/', it seems like it is checking all the url's and the word which matches is display but it is not omitting, '/'